# Pulseaudio C API: create a null sink

Tags: c, pulseaudio

I am trying to create 2 simple programs that are basically the parec-simple and pacat-simple examples from the [pulseaudio documentation](https://freedesktop.org/software/pulseaudio/doxygen/examples.html). The only difference is that I would like to create a null sink, equivalent of

```
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=steam
```

(see example [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60837/record-a-programs-output-with-pulseaudio)) which I would then use instead of the default device on both ends - playback and record.

My question is: how can I create this null sink using pulseaudio's C API? From what I saw, pulse/simple.h does not contain any function definition to do this, so I guess I would have to use libpulse.

Comment: Hey Copil, did you find a way to do it?

Comment: @Barthy: yes, see the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find the pulseaudio API for it so I just use the pactl interface directly.

For anyone interested, here is a sample code that worked for me. I just used [popen](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) to execute the pactl command to create a (null) sink:

```
static bool createNullPaSink(const std::string& sinkName, int* paHandleId) {

    // this is the command to create the null sink with some specific setup (format, channels, rate, etc.0
    std::string pacmd = "pactl load-module module-null-sink latency_msec=100 format=s16le rate=48000 channels=2 channel_map=front-left,front-right sink_properties=device.description=QM sink_name=" + sinkName;
    // execute the pactl command
    FILE* f = popen(pacmd.c_str(), "r");
    if (!f) {
        // creating the sink failed
        return false;
    }
    
    // now get the handle of the sink by reading the output of the popen command above
    std::array<char, 128> buffer;
    std::string spaHandleId;
    while (fgets(buffer.data(), 128, f) != NULL) {
        spaHandleId += buffer.data();
    }
    auto returnCode = pclose(f);
    if (returnCode) {
        return false;
    }

    *paHandleId = std::stoi(spaHandleId);
    
    return true;
}
```